# ng-maxlength="1" não funciona - Angular

Tags: angularjs

Boa tarde, tenho um input do tipo "number" e preciso limitar o número de caracteres, mas da forma que estou fazendo não está funcionando.

```
<input id="turbidez" type="number" ng-maxlength="7" ng-model="turbidez.turbidez" required />
```

Quando eu tiro o tipo do campo "number", o ng-maxlength funciona, o problema é que eu não posso deixar campo sem tipo, pois irá afetar outras partes do sistema.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A a propriedade `maxlength` determina um valor máximo de *comprimento*, útil para conteúdo do tipo *string*.

Um valor numérico possui, ao invés disso, um *valor máximo*.

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
<input id="turbidez" 
 type="number" 
 max="9999999" // Máximo valor com 7 casas decimais.
 ng-model="turbidez.turbidez" 
 required />
```

Exemplo funcional:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.turbidez = 5000;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller='myController'>
    
    <input name="turbidez" 
 type="number" 
 max="9999999" // Máximo valor com 7 casas decimais.
 ng-model="turbidez" 
 required />
 
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.turbidez.$error.required">
      Valor obrigatório.</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.turbidez.$error.number">
      Valor não é um número.</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.turbidez.$error.max">
      Valor acima do aceitável.</span>
    </div>

    <br/>
    
    <tt>valor = {{turbidez}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.turbidez.$valid = {{myForm.turbidez.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.turbidez.$error = {{myForm.turbidez.$error}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
    <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>

    
  </form>
</div>
```

[Fonte.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Comment: Tentei com max="9999999" e ng-max="9999999", mas não funcionou.

Comment: @jveing Incluí um exemplo funcional na resposta.

Comment: OnoSendai, consegui resolver o problema. Não exatamente como eu queria, que era limitar realmente o número de caracteres, mas agora ele mostra uma mensagem ao passar da quantidade máxima. Utilizei o exemplo que você passou max="9999999".